# Iframe src being intercepted by BURP Suite and changed to load another Url on Iframe

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe that loads a third party website, however it is possible to intercept the request using burp suite and change the original src of the iframe on the GET request and give it another src. Is it possible to counter this in java.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely possible. You can add "Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content" headers to the http response headers with Java. In this way, the resources -you do not want- will be blocked.

1. [More info](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content)
2. [More info about Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)